# How do I "trash" a custom post type post while logged in as Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, user-roles, members

I am using the members plugin and have a custom post type of "listing"

When I navigate to listings in the backend, I can edit. quickedit, and view.  There is no option to trash.  I am logged in as the admin.

```
add_action('init', 'listing_init');
function listing_init()  
{  
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Listing', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Listing', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Listing'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Listing'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Listing'),
    'new_item' => __('New Listing'),
    'view_item' => __('View Listing'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Listing'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Listing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Listing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_ui_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'listing',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category')
  );
 register_post_type('listing',$args);
 }
```

this is the functions.php custom post type code that I am using. Everything else works great.

Inside the members plugin I have roles for delete_listing and delete_listings (which I think is not necessary)

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you need [one of these Admin capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator)?

- delete_others_pages
- delete_others_posts
- delete_pages
- delete_plugins
- delete_posts
- delete_private_pages
- delete_private_posts
- delete_published_pages
- delete_published_posts

Unless you've modified the default capabilities for Administrator, to remove one or more of these capabilities, you should be able to delete any Post (of any Post-Type) as an Admin user.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [tutorial on how to properly apply capabilities with the Members plugin for CPTs](http://webtide.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/how-to-use-the-members-plugin-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-type/).

The gist is to make sure you have all of the proper caps, not just the delete_ cap.